# Simple user permissions database structure

Tags: database, database-design

I'm looking for a right solution for database structure regarding user permissions.

Tables:

- `users`
- `companies` (relevant columns: `id`)
- `projects` (relevant columns: `id`,`company_id`)
- `jobs` (relevant columns: `id`, `company_id`,`project_id`)

Scenarios I want to accomplish is to have specific user and/or users assigned to:

- all the projects within company ("Cindy is assigned to all projects and all jobs within company")
- select projects within company ("Cindy is assigned to three out of five projects and is assigned to all jobs within those three projects")
- selected job(s) within project(s) ("Cindy is assigned to five jobs out of ten within one project and two jobs within the other project")

I think about separate `permissions` table where I just insert permissions to relevant jobs and to use the relevant columns from `jobs` table to cascade permissions upwards. In other words - if a user has permission for a specific job then it also has permission for parent project and parent company.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74a4d3/2

Comment: Does your database have the ability to use user roles?  Those would help greatly with accomplishing this task.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB so yes. Should I use database's `role` functionality when I want to manage web app users access to specific places inside app? I'm not talking about giving access to db directly to anyone just in case I sound like I want to

Comment: This is what roles are made for!  You can nest roles within roles (so accomplish a mirroring of your company/project/job structure).  Even if you aren't giving users direct database access, you can use the database's roles to manage permissions.  Otherwise, you're going to end up reinventing the wheel, so to speak.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/roles_overview/

Comment: P.S. this does mean making database user accounts for the user instead of using a "users" table.  If that's not acceptable then you will have to go back to the permissions table idea.  In any case, I wouldn't recommend a database table named "users" specifically because I confuse it with the database's internal user metadata table.

Comment: For now it would be too much hassle to migrate everything, but it will be something I will keep in mind for the future when we will have more time for refining database structure. For now though I need to stick with separate `users` table because we have quite a lot of things already there and given we want to add social authentication I will pass (for now at least!). Thanks for the link - I will dive into it anyway just to broaden my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposed table structure for `permissions`:

```
USER_ID     OBJ_TYPE      OBJ_ID     PERMISSION
JDOE        COMPANY       1          1-READONLY
JDOE        COMPANY       2          2-READWRITE
JDOE        PROJECT       1          2-READWRITE
```

Then code to check user access could look something like:

```
SELECT MAX(permission) FROM permissions 
 WHERE user_id = :USERID
   AND (  (obj_type = 'JOB' and obj_id = :JOBID)
       OR (obj_type = 'PROJECT' and obj_id = :PROJECTID)
       OR (obj_type = 'COMPANY' and obj_id = :COMPANYID))
```

Comment: I updated my answer with relevant SQL fiddle to shed some more light on what I am about. Nevertheless, your answer seems like I could loop through on the backend side using similar logic.